# What does Disqus API 'reputation' score mean?

Tags: api, disqus

On the Disqus moderation page, you can see each commenter's reputation badge: High Rep, Low Rep, Average, and undefined. If you request the comment data using the Disqus API, it returns a reputation number `"reputation":1.233156` instead of the default badges.

What does this reputation number mean? And how does this score translate to badges? Also, how is the score calculated?

[(Reference)](http://blog.disqus.com/post/18875154463/the-all-new-disqus-moderation-introducing-user)

Answer (score 0):

Was wondering the same thing, from an API query I saw:

```
  'rep': 3.3011290000000004,
  'reputation': 3.3011290000000004,
  'reputationLabel': 'High'
```

On the [definitions page](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1131785-available-public-api-data) it confirms that rep and reputation are the same thing (obvious..)

[Here](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466247-user-reputation) are the descriptions of what it is on the Disqus site.

I looked around, they don't seem to reveal their exact formula for calculating the score but you can guess the nature of it from what it says there: everyone starts at 'average', lots of activity and up-votes makes it 'high' and deleted by moderator, marked as spam, flagged by other users makes it low.

Badges does not seem to be adequately defined anywhere not totally sure what it is but it is possibly something assigned by the moderators or users themselves rather than calculated by the system, the small icons in the usernames [here](https://disqus.com/home/discussion/channel-discussdisqus/custom_user_badges/) for example.